# Append previous transaction date SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that shows customer_id, product_id, browse_date, purchase_date, and the difference between the browse and purchase date. It looks something like this.

```
id  pID  b_Date     p_Date   
1   001  7/20/2014  7/20/2014
1   001  7/20/2014  7/20/2014
1   002  7/20/2014  7/20/2014
2   001  7/20/2014  7/20/2014
2   001  7/20/2014  8/01/2014
2   002  7/25/2014  8/01/2014
2   002  7/26/2014  8/01/2014
2   002  7/28/2014  8/01/2014
2   002  7/28/2014  8/01/2014
```

What is the most efficient way to append the most recent purchase date for each customer previous the latest purchase.  So, the result would look something like this.

```
id  pID  b_Date     p_Date     latest_purchase_date
1   001  7/20/2014  7/20/2014  'N/A'
1   001  7/20/2014  7/20/2014  'N/A'
1   002  7/20/2014  7/20/2014  'N/A'
2   001  7/20/2014  7/20/2014  'N/A'
2   001  7/20/2014  8/01/2014  7/20/2014
2   002  7/25/2014  8/01/2014  7/20/2014
2   002  7/26/2014  8/01/2014  7/20/2014
2   002  7/28/2014  8/01/2014  7/20/2014
2   002  7/28/2014  8/01/2014  7/20/2014
```

I'm on Teradata 13.1

Comment: In Postgres I'd use the `lag()` function. Does Teradata support window functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no LAG in Teradata, but it's easy to rewrite.

As there are multiple rows with the same p_date you need to keep track whenever it changes.

```
SELECT id, pid, b_date, p_date
   ,MAX(last_dt) -- fill the NULLs with the last date
    OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY p_date, last_dt DESC
          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM
 (
   SELECT id, pid, b_date, p_date,
      NULLIF(MIN(p_date) -- return the date only when there's a change, otherwise NULL
             OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY p_date
                   ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
            , p_date) AS last_dt
   FROM vt
 ) AS dt
```